# Performance optimisation : null check in Update()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a basic AI for enemies in my space shooter project.
In my EnemyAI script, I've a `public Transform target` that I set when I instantiate a enemy. In the Update loop, I'm looking at the target, then moving using `transform.towards` and everything works fine. The problem is, the `target` can die, so I need to check if it is not null before doing all that. Problem is : apparently doing a simple `if(target == null)` is really bad performance wise, and I need to do it in Update. What should be the best approach to achieve that without having performance problems (let say I want 500 enemies at once). Should I still do it every X frame, cache the position of the target till the next check and move toward that cached result ? That could work but it would introduce jitter if the time between two check if too long.

I couldn't find any "easy" way but I hope there is one, it looks like something really simple and it's causing a lot of troubles :/

Comment: Where do you get the idea that checking null pointers is an expensive operation? I don't know much about the internals of C#, but for most programming languages it's as fast (probably faster) than an integer comparison.

Comment: Please add your code... Anyaway null check is very cheap. You can do a hundreds per frame

Comment: This question refers to Unity objects, and null comparison it NOT fast. https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Avoid-null-comparisons-against-UnityEngine.Object-subclasses

Comment: What code do you want me to add ? I don't see how it could help as it is a single line of code that is problematic and it is already stated in my post

Comment: I believe you can solve this with a callback which register to target's on Destroy. I am not sure how costly it would be though

Comment: @AliKanat Now that is a good hint ! I'll look into that thank you

Comment: Or you subscribe to an event like `Player.OnPlayerDied()`. If the event is called, you set the target to `null` and the property `Enemy.HasTarget` to `false`. On sight of the player you set `Enemy.HasTarget` to `true`, of course. This way, you can simply type `if (Enemy.HasTarget)...`

Answer (score 2):

- Null checks are not **that** expensive.
- Coroutines can help spread the load over multiple frames. But carefully read about their memory usage / garbage collection problems.
- You could speed that up using the ECS system (Entity Component System) in combination with C# Jobs (multithreaded)
- Use the Profiler (Window -> Profiler) or (Window -> Analysis -> Profiler in 2018.3) to analyse what's actually taking long.
- A for-each is bad (garbage-collection wise) compared to a normal for.
- If you set position and rotation, group the two calls by using [SetPositionAndRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetPositionAndRotation.html)

Comment: 1. Please look at https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Avoid-null-comparisons-against-UnityEngine.Object-subclasses. There is a lot of threads that says it is.
2. You can do the same using `if(Time.frameCount % X == 0)` to spread work over frames.
3. AFAIK, Unity objects are not thread-safe

Comment: Well that's relative. Sure, it's more expensive than simple bool checks, but 500 null-checks won't cost you 5ms. For 60 fps you are allowed to use up 16ms per frame. So I'd make sure to optimize the bottlenecks first. Have you thought about an array where you filter out dead enemies when they die?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, plus I've a bool isAlive on my Player class, so I won't need to check for GameObject anymore. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2):

Note null check with UnityEngine.Object children are NOT the standard C# null checks.  This [description](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Avoid-null-comparisons-against-UnityEngine.Object-subclasses) that Jetbrains provides in relation to the Rider IDE and analysis tool gets into the details.  The basic idea is that the C# script hands off the null check to the underlying C++ engine structure.

I have not had the need for it but I have seen other's code that keeps a simple list of UnityEngine.Object references.  They add a reference to the object to the list when it is created.  Then remove it from the list on destruction. Update() can then use a faster test in the list.  Where speed is critical, you just test the list not the object.  Of course, an approach other than a list could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up and tested it and yes you can do this with a callback function which will be registered to your target's `OnDestroy` method. Your `Player script` should access target script and delegate the method like this:

```
public GameObject target;
private TargetScript myTargetScript;

void Start () {
    myTargetScript = target.GetComponent<TargetScript>();
    myTargetScript.OnDestroyEvnt += OnDestroyListener;
}

private void OnDestroyListener(MonoBehaviour instance)
{
    Debug.Log("Callback is called");
}
```

Also `Target script` should be like this:

```
public event OnDestroyDelegate OnDestroyEvnt;

public delegate void OnDestroyDelegate(MonoBehaviour instance);

void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(DestroyCoroutine());
}   

private void OnDestroy()
{
    if (this.OnDestroyEvnt != null)
    {
        this.OnDestroyEvnt(this);
    }
}

IEnumerator DestroyCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

I used a coroutine to destroy the object after 5 secs. It is actually irrelevant in your case. I adopted this code from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-can-unitys-ondestroy-be-subscribed-to.286691/).

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid it logic-wise, make a coroutine that only runs when you assign the target, and if the target is null, end the coroutine, that coroutine should have a...

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

that way it will act as a kind of `LateUpdate`.

And check every frame...

```
while (target != null)
```

You would be still checking every frame the null, but you will only check the `target = null` once.

Comment: In your way you check it 100% of the time, on mine, you only check it between the assignment of the target and the first time a null appears. So not every frame. In other words, you would be avoiding checking while waiting for the next assign of target.